# Using Java Policy Files to make Applications Exempt from JCE Restrictions

Tags: java, security, cryptography, jce

I have a Java application that performs some cryptography using AES-256; as you know this requires the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. However, I do not want to have to install these on all machines the application is distribitued to. So after some digging I came accross this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#ExemptApps

Which is appearantly a way to include policy files within your JAR. From that article the steps to accomplish this are:

> Step 1: Write and Compile Your Application Code
>
> Step 2: Create a Permission Policy File Granting Appropriate
>   Cryptographic Permissions
>
> Step 3: Prepare for Testing
>
> > Step 3a: Apply for Government Approval From the Government Mandating
> >     Restrictions.
> >
> > Step 3b: Get a Code-Signing Certificate
> >
> > Step 3c: Bundle the Application and Permission Policy File into a JAR
> >     file
> >
> > Step 3d: Sign the JAR file
> >
> > Step 3e: Set Up Your Environment Like That of a User in a Restricted
> >     Country
> >
> > Step 3f: (only for apps using exemption mechanisms) Install a Provider
> >     Implementing the Exemption Mechanism Specified in the Permission
> >     Policy File
>
> Step 4: Test Your Application
>
> Step 5: Apply for U.S. Government Export Approval If Required
>
> Step 6: Deploy Your Application

What I am wondering about are steps 3b - 3d. How should I sign this JAR file? Who should sign it? Can I use a self signed certificate for signing that the clients do not have? Is there any authentication done on this signature?

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Surely steps 3a and 5 are infinitely more of a hurdle than installing a couple of JARs?

Comment: @EJP I'm assuming steps 3a and 5 are only nescissary if you live in a country where cryptographic strength is limited, which, thankfully, I do not.

Comment: It used to be that for crypto providers only a code signing certificate from Sun or, oddly, IBM, could be used. The roots for those certificates were hard-coded somewhere in the Java library, and the truststore is never consulted. Furthermore, you could only get those certificates from Sun by agreeing to abide by US export control rules. I would not surprised if things have changed since then however.

Comment: This PITA is a major reason why some people just go with Bouncycastle.

Comment: @GregS nope, that's still the same, but that is for crypto providers, not specifically for applications (and yes, I have just renewed one for my company) - reapplying took a lot less time too (the previous one was only received after a month or so of complete radio silence)

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you indeed would send a certification request to Oracle to get the permissions, similar to getting one to sign provider(s) - it might depend a lot on the type of company you are working for if you can get one - reason being that I *think* the trust store within the JCE does not contain many certificates

Comment: @owlstead, I work at a large bank, with deep pockets, I'll let you guys know of the result.